# Mediacontroller back button not work (not even called)

Tags: java, android

I'm also trying to put the videoview inside scrollview so I could scroll and the video will disappear
and I tried to use textureview but when I tried to insert video its didtn saw it
so I tried video view and its looked like when I write `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

in the videoview XML its don't know what to do and I don't want to use dp size because I want it to fit to every phone
so the problem now is when I click back button its not work and the mediaController still show (back button needs to close the mediaController and if its already close so finish activity)

```
public class aboutus extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;
    VideoView videoView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    public static Integer size = 20;
    boolean flag = false;
    MediaController mediaController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_abouus);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar3);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("בית מילר חיפה");
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_aboutus);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);

        String videopath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.millervideo;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videopath);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.seekTo(1);
        dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0,0,KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_L,0,KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_ON));

        mediaController = new MediaController(this) {
            @Override
            public void hide() {
                //do Nothing
                super.hide();
            }

            //Handle BACK button
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
                if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                    Toast.makeText(aboutus.this, "This is my Toast message!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    super.hide();//Hide mediaController
                    finish();//Close this activity
                    return true;//If press Back button, finish here
                }
                //If not Back button, other button (volume) work as usual.
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }

        };

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);


        String string="try";

        textView.setText(string);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        textView.setTextSize(size);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.plus_size:
                size++;
                //Toast.makeText(aboutus.this, String.valueOf(size), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                textView.setTextSize(size);
                break;
            case R.id.minus_size:
                size = size - 1;
                //Toast.makeText(aboutus.this, String.valueOf(size), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                textView.setTextSize(size);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.aboutusmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```